# Facebook login response became "undefined" after putting code "window.location.href"

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, authentication

I'm implementing an application using Facebook login as an optional login approach. After the user logged in with the Facebook account, I write the username into a cookie and want to redirect to the index pager of the website. Everything works OK before I put the redirection code into the file. Here is the code. It's in javascript.

```
$(document).ready( function(){    
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'myAppId',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});  
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
 if (response.status === 'connected') {

      var userName = testAPI(response);
  var today = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*30);
  document.cookie="138do_uid="+userName+";expires="+expire.toGMTString()+"path=/";

  window.location.assign("myWebpage");

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {      
     FB.login();
  } else {      
     FB.login();
  }
}); 
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function testAPI(response) {
  var myWindow = window.open("","MsgWindow","width=200,height=100");
var userName;

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    userName = response.name;
    myWindow.document.write("<p>" + userName + "</p>");


});
return userName;
}
});
```

Before I added the line "window.location.assign("myWebpage");", the value of response.name is correct and the name is showed correctly in the pop-up window (The pop-up window is for testing). However, if I add the "window.location" line, the value of response.name suddenly becomes "undefined" and it also showed "undefined" in the pop-up window.

Anyone could tell me what the problem is?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: OK. Problem solved. I think it was an asynchronizing problem. I moved the redirection code into the FB.api() function call and it works well now. The modified code is listed below: 


    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  userName = response.name;
  myWindow.document.write("<p>" + userName + "</p>");
 
  var today = new Date();
     var expire = new Date();
     expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*30);
  document.cookie="138do_uid="+userName+";expires="+expire.toGMTString()+"path=/";
  window.location.assign("myWebpage");
 });

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to answer my own question, because my reputation is below 10. How can I get more reputation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two major parts to this. The first one is your Facebook web app will only work on your domain space. So first I would try redirecting to a page on your domain space.

The second part is every page in you app that you want to use the Facebook API must have a Facebook object built on it and you have to verify that your user is logged in and they have granted your app the correct permissions to run whatever query you choose to run.

If you wish to expand further on the premise of your app I would be glad to help you out more.

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks for the reply. I was actually redirecting to my domain space. The www.google.com was just an example I used when posting this question. I have changed it to "myWebpage" to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Ok cool. So the page you redirect to has a Facebook object on it aswell?

Comment: Yes. Now I'm thinking if it is some asynchronizing problem? So the later code get executed before the response from Facebook arrived? I was trying to attach some images showing the problem, but it told me that I must have 10 reputations to do that.

Comment: I know I need 50 rep to comment on your post. lol You get more rep by answering other peoples question and by getting up-voted. You can lose rep by getting down voted.